# how can use ng-click in angularjs in mustache template

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, mustache

> Here is a JSFiddle of your code snippet : jsfiddle.net/haroldcampbell/r45ffrea
>   its time table generator
>    ng-click working in static element you can see (superman) in below ,
>   but not working in external temlpates

---

> {{fromBreakHour}}:{{fromBreakTime}} {{toBreakHour}}:{{toBreakTime}} click="deletebreak('{{fromBreakHour}}','{{fromBreakTime}}')" style="float:right; >?>cursor:pointer;">X this not working at all

---

> i dont want use angular template 
>   This example is timetable generator you can give session time and break times
>
> ### AngularJs

```js
      var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

                app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.jasons = [];
                    $scope.breaks = [];
                    $scope.sessionTime = 30;
                    $scope.gap = 5;
                    $scope.startTime = 9;
                    $scope.startTimeMinute = 0;
                    $scope.timesUp = 17;
                    $scope.timesUpMinute = 0;
                    $scope.overflow = false;
                    $scope.breakFromHour = 12;
                    $scope.breakFromMinte = 30;
                    $scope.breakToHour = 13;
                    $scope.breakToMinte = 30;
                    load($scope.sessionTime, $scope.gap, $scope.startTime, $scope.startTimeMinute, $scope.timesUp, $scope.timesUpMinute, $scope.overflow);

                    $scope.loadPage = function () {
                        $scope.jasons.splice(0);
                        load($scope.sessionTime, $scope.gap, $scope.startTime, $scope.startTimeMinute, $scope.timesUp, $scope.timesUpMinute, $scope.overflow);
                    };

                    function load(sessionTime, gap, startTime, startTimeMinute, timesUp, timesUpMinute, overflow) {
                        console.clear();
                        if (gap == "") {
                            gap = 0;
                        }
                        var classActive = "activate";
                        var classDeactibe = "deactivate";
                        var isWorth = (parseInt(sessionTime) * 1) / 20;
                        var mainTime = new Date(2012, 1, 1, parseInt(startTime), parseInt(startTimeMinute), 0, 0);
                        var endTime = new Date(2012, 1, 1, parseInt(timesUp), parseInt(timesUpMinute), 0, 0);

                        var multiBreak = [{ fh: -1, ft: 0, th: 0, tt: 0 }];
                        if ($scope.breaks.length != 0) {
                            jQuery.each(multiBreak, function (i, val) {
                                if (val.fh == -1) {
                                    multiBreak.splice(0);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        jQuery.each($scope.breaks, function (i, val) {
                            multiBreak.push({
                                fh: val.fromBreakHour,
                                ft: val.fromBreakTime,
                                th: val.toBreakHour,
                                tt: val.toBreakTime
                            });
                        });

                        //////////////////// while /////////////////////////
                        while (mainTime.getTime() < endTime.getTime()) {
                            var starsLogHour = mainTime.getHours();
                            var starsLogMinutes = mainTime.getMinutes();
                            var startpTimeSpan = mainTime.getTime();
                            ////set time
                            mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(sessionTime));
                            var endLogTime = mainTime.getTime();
                            var endLogHour = mainTime.getHours();
                            var endLogMinutes = mainTime.getMinutes();
                            //tims up
                            if (mainTime.getTime() > endTime.getTime()) {

                                var defreenceInBreak = (mainTime.getTime() - endTime.getTime()) / 60000;
                                mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() - parseInt(defreenceInBreak));

                                var startCheckTime = new Date(2012, 1, 1, starsLogHour, starsLogMinutes, 0, 0);

                                var checkWorth = (mainTime.getTime() - startCheckTime.getTime()) / 60000;

                                if (checkWorth >= isWorth) {
                                    var counter = 0;
                                    jQuery.each(multiBreak, function (iv, val) {
                                        ++counter;
                                        var checkFromBetween = new Date(2012, 1, 1, val.fh, val.ft, 0, 0);
                                        var checkToBetween = new Date(2012, 1, 1, val.th, val.tt, 0, 0);
                                        var deffBetween = (checkToBetween.getTime() - checkFromBetween.getTime()) / 60000;

                                        if (checkFromBetween.getTime() >= startCheckTime.getTime() && checkToBetween.getTime() <= mainTime.getTime()) {
                                            console.log('over time');

                                            var backToStart = (mainTime.getTime() - checkFromBetween.getTime()) / 60000;
                                            mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() - parseInt(backToStart));

                                            var checkFromWorth = new Date(2012, 1, 1, starsLogHour, starsLogMinutes, 0, 0);
                                            var checkToWorth = new Date(2012, 1, 1, mainTime.getHours(), mainTime.getMinutes(), 0, 0);
                                            var checkWorthFromTo = (checkToWorth.getTime() - checkFromWorth.getTime()) / 60000;
                                            if (checkWorthFromTo >= isWorth) {
                                                console.log(starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes, mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes());
                                                console.log("============================");
                                                $scope.jasons.push({
                                                    from: starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes,
                                                    to: mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes(),
                                                    isTime: true,
                                                    className: classActive
                                                });
                                            }

                                            mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(deffBetween));

                                            starsLogHour = mainTime.getHours();
                                            starsLogMinutes = mainTime.getMinutes();

                                            var backRest = (endLogTime - mainTime.getTime()) / 60000;

                                            mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(backRest));

                                            if (counter == multiBreak.length) {
                                                if (mainTime.getTime() <= endTime.getTime()) {
                                                    var checkLegFromWorth = new Date(2012, 1, 1, starsLogHour, starsLogMinutes, 0, 0);
                                                    var checkLegToWorth = new Date(2012, 1, 1, mainTime.getHours(), mainTime.getMinutes(), 0, 0);
                                                    var checkLegFromToWorth = (checkLegToWorth.getTime() - checkLegFromWorth.getTime()) / 60000;
                                                    if (checkLegFromToWorth >= isWorth) {
                                                        console.log(starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes, mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes());
                                                        console.log("============================");
                                                        $scope.jasons.push({
                                                            lable: starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes + mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes(),
                                                            isTime: true,
                                                            className: classActive
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    var t = (mainTime.getTime() - endTime.getTime()) / 60000;
                                                    mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() - parseInt(t));
                                                    var checkLegFromWorth2 = new Date(2012, 1, 1, starsLogHour, starsLogMinutes, 0, 0);
                                                    var checkLegToWorth2 = new Date(2012, 1, 1, mainTime.getHours(), mainTime.getMinutes(), 0, 0);
                                                    var checkLegFromToWorth2 = (checkLegToWorth2.getTime() - checkLegFromWorth2.getTime()) / 60000;
                                                    if (checkLegFromToWorth2 >= isWorth) {
                                                        console.log(starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes, mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes());
                                                        console.log("============================");
                                                        $scope.jasons.push({
                                                            from: starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes,
                                                            to: mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes(),
                                                            isTime: true,
                                                            className: "activate"
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            console.log(starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes, mainTime.getHours(), mainTime.getMinutes());
                                            console.log("============================");
                                            $scope.jasons.push({
                                                from: starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes,
                                                to: mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes(),
                                                isTime: true,
                                                className: "activate"
                                            });
                                            if (mainTime.getTime() <= endTime.getTime()) {
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                break;
                            }

                            jQuery.each(multiBreak, function (i, val) {
                                var multiBreakStart = new Date(2012, 1, 1, val.fh, val.ft, 0, 0);
                                var multiBreakEnd = new Date(2012, 1, 1, val.th, val.tt, 0, 0);
                                /////////////////////
                                if (between(mainTime.getTime(), multiBreakStart.getTime(), multiBreakEnd.getTime())) {
                                    console.log('break in time');
                                    mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() - parseInt(sessionTime));
                                    var defreenceGap = (multiBreakStart.getTime() - mainTime.getTime()) / 60000;

                                    mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() + defreenceGap);

                                    if (defreenceGap > 0 & defreenceGap >= isWorth) {
                                        console.log("manipulate time", starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes, mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes());
                                        console.log("============================");
                                        $scope.jasons.push({
                                            from: starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes,
                                            to: mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes(),
                                            isTime: true,
                                            className: classActive
                                        });
                                    }

                                    var defreence = ((multiBreakEnd.getTime() - multiBreakStart.getTime()) / 60000);

                                    mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() + defreence);

                                    starsLogHour = mainTime.getHours();
                                    starsLogMinutes = mainTime.getMinutes();
                                    mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(sessionTime));

                                    var defreenceAfterGap = ((mainTime.getTime() - endTime.getTime()) / 60000);

                                    if (defreenceAfterGap > 0) {
                                        mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() - parseInt(defreenceAfterGap));
                                    }

                                    endLogHour = mainTime.getHours();
                                    endLogMinutes = mainTime.getMinutes();
                                } else if (multiBreakStart.getTime() >= startpTimeSpan && multiBreakEnd.getTime() <= mainTime.getTime()) {
                                    if (mainTime.getTime() > multiBreakEnd.getTime()) {
                                        console.log("break out time");

                                        var outStartEndDefreence = ((multiBreakEnd.getTime() - multiBreakStart.getTime()) / 60000);

                                        var fromOutBreakDiff = (mainTime.getTime() - multiBreakStart.getTime()) / 60000;

                                        mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() - parseInt(fromOutBreakDiff));

                                        var one = new Date(2012, 1, 1, starsLogHour, starsLogMinutes, 0, 0);
                                        var tow = new Date(2012, 1, 1, mainTime.getHours(), mainTime.getMinutes(), 0, 0);
                                        var firstBreakWorth = (tow.getTime() - one.getTime()) / 60000;
                                        if (firstBreakWorth >= isWorth) {
                                            console.log("ok , break out time" + starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes, mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes());
                                            console.log("============================");
                                            $scope.jasons.push({
                                                from: starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes,
                                                to: mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes(),
                                                isTime: true,
                                                className: classActive
                                            });
                                        }

                                        mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(outStartEndDefreence));

                                        starsLogHour = mainTime.getHours();
                                        starsLogMinutes = mainTime.getMinutes();

                                        var checkdeff = 0;
                                        if (endLogTime > mainTime.getTime()) {
                                            checkdeff = (endLogTime - mainTime.getTime()) / 60000;
                                        }

                                        mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(checkdeff));

                                        endLogHour = mainTime.getHours();
                                        endLogMinutes = mainTime.getMinutes();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            var oneMin = new Date(2012, 1, 1, starsLogHour, starsLogMinutes, 0, 0);
                            var towMin = new Date(2012, 1, 1, mainTime.getHours(), mainTime.getMinutes(), 0, 0);
                            var minWorth = (towMin.getTime() - oneMin.getTime()) / 60000;
                            if (minWorth >= isWorth) {
                                console.log('ok', starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes, endLogHour + ":" + endLogMinutes);
                                $scope.jasons.push({
                                    from: starsLogHour + ":" + starsLogMinutes,
                                    to: mainTime.getHours() + ":" + mainTime.getMinutes(),
                                    isTime: true,
                                    className: classActive
                                });
                                /// gap time ////////
                                console.log("-----------------------");
                                mainTime.setMinutes(mainTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(gap));
                                if (mainTime.getTime() > endTime.getTime()) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                var endGapLogHour = mainTime.getHours();
                                var endGapLogMinutes = mainTime.getMinutes();
                                console.log('*********', endLogHour + ":" + endLogMinutes, endGapLogHour + ":" + endGapLogMinutes);
                                console.log("============================");
                                $scope.jasons.push({
                                    from: endLogHour + ":" + endLogMinutes,
                                    to: endGapLogHour + ":" + endGapLogMinutes,
                                    isTime: false,
                                    className: classDeactibe
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        //// load
                        var template = $('#template').html();
                        Mustache.parse(template);
                        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, { temp: $scope.jasons });
                        $('#timeTable').html(rendered);
                    };

                    function between(x, min, max) {
                        return x > min && x < max;
                    }

                    $scope.deleteBreak = function (from, to) {
                        alert(from, to);
                    }

                    $scope.addBreaks = function () {
                        if (parseInt($scope.breakFromHour) > parseInt($scope.breakToHour)) {
                            alert('select currect break times');
                            return false;
                        } else if (parseInt($scope.breakFromHour) == parseInt($scope.breakToHour)) {
                            if ($scope.breakFromMinte > $scope.breakToMinte || $scope.breakFromMinte == $scope.breakToMinte) {
                                  alert('select currect break times');
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        var flag = true;
                        if ($scope.breaks.length != 0) {
                            jQuery.each($scope.breaks, function (i, val) {
                                var fromTime = new Date(2012, 1, 1, val.fromBreakHour, val.fromBreakTime, 0, 0);
                                var toTime = new Date(2012, 1, 1, val.toBreakHour, val.toBreakTime, 0, 0);
                                var newfromTime = new Date(2012, 1, 1, $scope.breakFromHour, $scope.breakFromMinte, 0, 0);
                                var newtoTime = new Date(2012, 1, 1, $scope.breakToHour, $scope.breakToMinte, 0, 0);

                                if (newfromTime.getTime() >= fromTime.getTime() && newfromTime.getTime() <= toTime.getTime()) {
                                      alert('select currect break times');
                                    flag = false;
                                    return false;
                                }
                                if (newfromTime.getTime() > fromTime.getTime() && newtoTime.getTime() > toTime.getTime()) {
                                      alert('select currect break times');
                                    flag = false;
                                    return false;
                                }

                                if (newtoTime.getTime() >= fromTime.getTime() && newtoTime.getTime() <= toTime.getTime()) {
                                     alert('select currect break times');
                                    flag = false;
                                    return false;
                                }
                                if (newfromTime.getTime() > fromTime.getTime() && newtoTime.getTime() > toTime.getTime()) {
                                     alert('select currect break times');
                                    flag = false;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        if (flag == false) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        $scope.breaks.push({
                            fromBreakHour: $scope.breakFromHour,
                            fromBreakTime: $scope.breakFromMinte,
                            toBreakHour: $scope.breakToHour,
                            toBreakTime: $scope.breakToMinte
                        });

                        $scope.breaks.sort(function (a, b) { return parseFloat(a.fromBreakHour) - parseFloat(b.fromBreakHour); });

                        console.log($scope.breaks);
                        var template = $('#templateBreak').html();
                        Mustache.parse(template);
                        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, { temp: $scope.breaks });
                        $('#breakDiv').html(rendered);

                          alert('successfully add');

                    }
                }]);

                app.directive('superman', [function () {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'A',
                        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                            elem.on('click', function () {
                                alert("dfgbdf");
                            });
                          
                        }
                    }
                }]);
```

```css
 .activate {
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            height: 40px;
            color: black;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 400px;
            padding-top: 14px;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
        }

        .deactivate {
            background-color: gray;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 15px;
            color: #696969;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
        }

        .breakClass {
            background-color: red;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 20px;
            color: #696969;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
        }
```

```html
 <link href="//codeseven.github.io/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//mustache.github.io/extras/mustache.js"></script>
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        


    <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
            {{#temp}}
            <div class="{{className}}">
                {{from}} {{to}}
            </div>
            {{/temp}}
        </script>

        <script id="templateBreak" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
            {{#temp}}
            <div superman class="breakClass">
                {{fromBreakHour}}:{{fromBreakTime}} {{toBreakHour}}:{{toBreakTime}} <a data-ng-click="deletebreak('{{fromBreakHour}}','{{fromBreakTime}}')" style="float:right; cursor:pointer;">X</a>
            </div>
            {{/temp}}
        </script>


            <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">
            sessionTime <input type="text" ng-model="sessionTime" placeholder="sessionTime"><br />
            startTime <input type="text" ng-model="startTime" placeholder="hour"> :<input type="text" ng-model="startTimeMinute" placeholder="minute"> <br />
            timesUp <input type="text" ng-model="timesUp" placeholder="hour">:<input type="text" ng-model="timesUpMinute" placeholder="minute"><br />
            gap <input type="text" ng-model="gap" placeholder="gap"><br />
            overflow<input type="checkbox" ng-model="overflow" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"><br />

            break time : from<input type="text" ng-model="breakFromHour" placeholder="hour">:<input type="text" ng-model="breakFromMinte" placeholder="minute"><br /> to<input type="text" ng-model="breakToHour" placeholder="hour">:<input type="text" ng-model="breakToMinte" placeholder="minute">
            <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addBreaks()" /><br />
            <br />
            <div id="breakDiv">

            </div>
            <br />
            <button ng-click="loadPage()">Reload</button> <hr />
            <hr />
            <div id="timeTable"></div>
            <hr /> <br />
            <div superman>superman</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What isn't working in your code? Here is a JSFiddle of your code snippet : http://jsfiddle.net/haroldcampbell/r45ffrea/.  Also, there are better ways of writing this code, perhaps as an AngularJS directive. This would remove all of the JQuery that you have in your controller.

Comment: in template i put ng-click it's not working

Comment: Look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/haroldcampbell/r45ffrea/3/ When I press the 'Reload' button with the `ng-click="loadPage()"` on line 36 I get an alert. I also get an alert when I press the `superman` div for the directive on line 40 which is wired to the directive on 417. As it stands you really should move all of the jquery code that you have from your controller, and out into a directive, or change the design of your code to a more AngularJS orientated approach.